# Could someone prove this formula in Northshield's paper?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $S(z,r)$ be a sphere in the half-space $\mathbb{C} \times [0,\infty)$, tangent to $\mathbb{C} \times \{0\}$ at $z$, with radius $r$. Could someone please prove the following result on mutually tangent sphers, found in [this paper](http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/sam.northshield/DescCThmV4.pdf) by Northshield:

[image: Northshield]

If someone could also put a diagram on the side it would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have two spheres tangent to the plane, and tangent to each other. The centres of the spheres and the corresponding tangent points with the plane form a trapezium, and considering the right-angled triangle at the top gives
$$ (r-s)^2 + \lvert z-w \rvert^2 = (r+s)^2, $$
since two spheres are tangent when the distance between the centres is the sum of the radii. Expanding this out gives
$$ \lvert z-w \rvert^2 = 4rs. $$

Now, applying this to the three spheres and three points gives
$$ \lvert z_i-z_j \rvert^2 = 4r_i r_j \\
\lvert z_j-z_k \rvert^2 = 4r_j r_k \tag{1} \\
\lvert z_k-z_i \rvert^2 = 4r_k r_i $$
Multiplying the three relations together and taking the square root gives
$$ \lvert z_i-z_j \rvert \cdot \lvert z_j-z_k \rvert \cdot \lvert z_k-z_i \rvert = 8r_i r_j r_k, $$
and if we divide this relation each equation in (1), we find
$$ 2r_i = \frac{\lvert z_i-z_j \rvert \cdot \lvert z_k-z_i \rvert}{\lvert z_i-z_j \rvert}, $$
as required.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that I'm very confused at how you used the three equations above to arrive at that one formula for r sub i. Could you please explain how you can arrive at this formula in another response?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on here. You didn't give enough context: like what the sphere's actually are. You should have at least linked the paper, if not defined all the notation. Having found the paper, you'll find that it actually follows from the previous result, in a similar way to my suggestion.

Comment: Here is the paper. http://faculty.plattsburgh.edu/sam.northshield/DescCThmV4.pdf Sorry I didn't give enough context there!
I got the first result by substituting x and y coordinates into the first result, but I'm really stuck for the next one as I can't find an algebraic way to prove it.

Comment: Right, I have edited my answer based on the paper. I suggest you edit the question to include some definitions, a link to the paper, and enough text to avoid including an image, so other people looking for the same topic can find this.

Comment: Thanks :) I read through the whole paper and came up with another question related to it.  I was going to ask it here in the comments but then I decided to create an entirely post here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447518/mutually-tangential-ellipses It's about finding new generalizations of the Descartes' Formula. Could you please have a look at it? Thanks again :)